# Am I adding this .on event listener incorrectly?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a `.on` event to a dynamically created element, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My table renders correctly, but nothing happens when I click on my `exp_col` div, not even an error message.

Have I done something incorrectly here?

```
    jQuery.each(items, function(index, item) {
        jQuery('<tr>')
            .addClass('item_class')
            .append(
                jQuery('<td/>')
                    .addClass('text')
                    .text('XXX')
                    .append(
                        jQuery('<div />')
                            .addClass('exp_col')
                            .text('More...')
                    )
                )

            .append(jQuery('<td/>').addClass('info').text('yyy'))
        .appendTo(table);

    });

    table.on("click", ".exp_col", function(e) { 
        myFunc( this );
    });
    table.appendTo(div);
```

Satpai's answer below is perfect, but instead of a `console.log`, if I was to call a function which did some CSS tinkering, and then removed the itself and added a new function. How could I accomplish that?

```
function myFunc(ele){
    //does some css stuff       
    jQuery(ele).off();
}

function myOtherFunc(ele){
    //removes the css stuff
    jQuery(ele).off();
}
```

My overall goal is to toggle two functions on and off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are creating elements dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

As per you code use:

```
//Move the event handler outside each block
table.on("click", ".exp_col", function() { 
    console.log('test');
});
table.appendTo(div);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Cheers Satpai!!

Comment: I wonder could you possibly expand your answer slightly Satpai? I've edited my question above.

Comment: @Daft, What you want to do with `myOtherFunc`? How and where are you using it?

Comment: `myOtherFunc` will do some CSS stuff, add `myFunc` again and then remove itself. So if I continuously click on `exp_col`, it will toggle back and forth between these two functions.